# Can I get HTML from Angular $compile or something similar?

Tags: angularjs, compilation

All,

My situation is similar to the following code.  I have an array of arrays where the first item in each array is used as the src for the ng-include.  The src is a complex set of custom directives and html that displays my animals in an attractive light.  No images or external links are in my src. I'd like my "Save It" function to save the fully rendered html between the span tags for later use.

I've been down the $compile route and end up getting stuff that is injected into the DOM and later rendered.  How can I get the html that the browser renderer sees?

Thanks for the help,
Jack

```
<div ng-repeat = "animals in theFarm" >
    <span ng-include src = 'animals[$index][0]' ></span >
    <a ng-click = "saveforLater($index)">Save It!</a >
</div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what the intent of `saveForLater` is?  Why would your user want to get HTML from that method, and where is it being saved to?

Comment: Why not just render all of the divs and selectively add `display: none` CSS to one's you want to "hide"

Comment: save the state...not the html

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but if you're trying to generate a full HTML page so that you can, yourself, save the generated HTML and use it as a template for yourself, I would just start with `document.body.innerHTML` to get the code.  More clarification might help.